# Need Help figuring issue when updating

Tags: cakephp

I am having problems with updating records using cakephp, this is the second time it happens and cant figure out what it is.. When I click on 'Submit' to update a record it always, always sends me to the login and it either logs me in or logs me out.. I dont understand..and it never updates the record it just jumps to the login stuff...the registration page same thing.. it was working before.. the only thing i changed.. was in app_controller instead of specifying the controls to allow I just added the '*' for all and now its not allowing to update or save anything.. the reason why i did that was because other pages that are under pages/contact_us or pages/about_us they were also being blocked by the Auth but with the '*' it went away..

In my App_Controller I have set it up to allow everything in the before filter, also in the controller itself i have a beforeFilter again saying the same thing.. I have tried about everything.. Here is my code

App_Controller

```
<?php
class AppController extends Controller {    

    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Javascript', 'Session'); 
    var $components = array('Auth', 'Session');

    function beforeFilter() {

       $this->Auth->allowedActions = array('*');
       $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;

      } 
}
?>
```

one of my controllers where I update

```
<?php

class DishRatingsController extends AppController {

      function list_ratings() { 

         $this->loadModel('Dish');
         $this->set('list_ratings', $this->Dish->find('all')); 
         $this->layout = 'master_layout';

      }

      function  rate_dish($id = null)
      {
        $this->layout = 'master_layout';

        $this->set('rate_dishes', $this->DishRating->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
               'Dish.id' => $id
          )
        )));

         if(!empty($this->data)) {         
             if($this->DishRating->save($this->data)) {                        
                $this->Session->setFlash("Rating Saved!");             
                 $this->redirect(array('action' => 'dish_ratings'));                  
             }         

        // set master layout
     }
    }

    function beforeFilter() {
       parent::beforeFilter(); 
       $this->Auth->allowedActions = array('*');

      } 

}
```

and My view where the submit button is

```
<?php

 echo $this->Form->create('DishRating', array('action' => 'rate_dish'));

 echo '<div><h3>Rate this Dish...</h3><p>You can rate this dish on this page and view other ratings from out customers...   </p></div>
    <table id="recipes">
     <tr>
         <td style="padding:10px;">';
         //<input type="hidden" name="userID" value="'.$rate_dishes[0]["DishRating"]["user_id"].'">
         echo $this->Form->hidden('id', array('value'=> $rate_dishes[0]["DishRating"]["user_id"]));
         //<input type="hidden" name="dish_id" value="'.$dish_rateid.'">
         echo $this->Form->hidden('rate_id', array('value'=> $rate_dishes[0]["DishRating"]["dish_id"]));
         echo '
         <span style="font-size: 20px; vertical-align:top;">Comments</span>
         </td>
         <td style="padding:10px;">';
         echo $this->Form->input('comments', array('type' => 'textarea', 'escape' => false , 'rows'=>'2','cols'=>'40', 'div' =>'false', 'label'=>''));
         //<textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="2"></textarea>
         echo '</td>
         <td>
         <div>
          <input name="star1000" value "1" type="radio" class="star"/>
          <input name="star1000" value="2" type="radio" class="star"/>
          <input name="star1000" value="3" type="radio" class="star"/>
          <input name="star1000" value="4" type="radio" class="star"/>
          <input name="star1000" value="5" type="radio" class="star"/> 
          </div>
         </td>
         <td>';
          // <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitrating" class="button"/>
         echo $this->Form->end(array('value'=>'Submit','name'=>'submitrating', 'type' =>'submit', 'class'=>'button'));
         echo '</td>
    <tr>
    </table>'; 

      print("<table id='results'><tr><th>User Name</th><th>Comments</th><th>Star Rating</th></tr>");
     $j = 0;

         foreach ($rate_dishes as $key => $rate_dish):

         print("<tr>");   
         print("<td width='20px'>");
         print("<p style='font-size:14px; color:blue; padding:0;'>".$rate_dishes[$j]['User']['username']."</p>");

         print("</td>");          
         print("<td width='100px'>");
         print("<p style='font-size:14px; color:blue; padding:0;'>".$rate_dishes[$j]['DishRating']['rate_comments']."</p>");
         print("</td>");
         print("<td width='100px'>");
         print("<div>");
         for($i = 1; $i < 6;$i++)
         {
          if($i != $rate_dishes[$j]['DishRating']['rate_num'])
          {
              echo  '<input name="star'.$j.'"  type="radio" class="star" disabled="disabled"/>';
          } 
          else 
          {
              echo  '<input name="star'.$j.'"  type="radio" class="star" disabled="disabled" checked="checked"/>';
          }
         }
         print("</div>");
         print("</td>");
         print("</tr>");
         $j++;
         endforeach;

         print("</table>");      

      if($j> 6)
     {
         echo '<div id="pageNavPosition"></div>
         <div>&nbsp;</div>';      


           echo $this->Html->script('padminbottom.js');
     }
  ?>
```

Please help solve this issue, I have researched, went to the cakePHP cookbook, nothing...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to allow every action of every controller your `beforeFilter` in app_controller should be like

```
   function beforeFilter() {

       $this->Auth->allow('*');
       $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;

  }
```

specifying `$this->allowedActions` is a different thing and in that case your Auth's `authorize` variable should be set to 'controller'. That means whenever a user requests an action he/she will be checked for their correct username, password. After that user will be checked by the `isAuthorize()` function implemented by every controller to grant access based on some additional logic.

Since you are not using that feature you don't need to specify `allowedAction`. If you are using controller for authorization specifying `allowedActions` will allow certain actions by default without checking them in `Controller::isAuthorize()`.

Comment: I had it with allow(*) and the same thing was happening.. no idea whats going on